# Windows 10 - can't ping default gateway

Tags: windows, networking

My Win 10 desktop suddenly can't connect to internet.
Getting "transmit failed. general failure" when pinging the default gateway 192.168.1.1.

Prior to the incident, the DHCP assigned IP address was 192.168.1.10.
Now it became 169.254.83.151 with empty default gateway.

The default gateway works fine as I can ping it from my Ubuntu laptop which can connect to the internet.

If I set IP & gateway address manually, Win 10 can ping the Ubuntu laptop & vice versa, but still getting RTO when pinging gateway.

Tried restarting PC, router, & re-intalling NIC driver but still no luck.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now it became 169.254.83.151

This is the "No DHCP, no connection" address.

Try TCP/IP Reset

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator

Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt

Then: ipconfig /flushdns

Now: restart the computer and test the connection.

This is the first repair you try for this issue. See what happens and if we need more repairs.

If the issue persists, try the following two steps in order:

**(a) From an admin command prompt, run DISM/SFC:**

dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  then
SFC  /SCANNOW   and restart, test.

**(b) Windows 10 Repair Install:**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

Finally then, if even the Repair does not work, back everything up and reinstall Windows. Something would have gone seriously wrong.

Comment: thanks for the response. did both command as admin & restarted, but issue persist.

Comment: I added some repair steps:  DISM/SFC  and then Windows 10 Repair Install.

Comment: Did you run DISM and SFC?  and then what happened?

Comment: sorry for the late response, the repair download took a while on my slow internet. tried both command & repair, but issue persists. i guess will need to clean install then?

Comment: I have augmented my answer. If both DISM and Repair do not work, then clean install (after backing up) is the only remaining answer.